# Mining and keeping UK minerals?

Tags: geology, minerals, mining

Is it legal to mine/collect and keep minerals in the UK for educational purposes?

I would also like to know if there are any notable mineral deposits located in the UK midlands.

Comment: There's a big difference between mining, and collecting your own samples, to keeping samples in a collection.

Comment: Can i go to forests, national parks or mineral deposits and mine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I go to forests, national parks or mineral deposits and mine

I think the basic answer to this question is No, or rather, not without the land owners permission.

For example it is illegal to remove pebbles from a beach: [Woman who 'stole' pebbles from a BEACH to decorate in her garden given police warning](http://www.mirror.co.uk/news/uk-news/woman-who-stole-pebbles-beach-2330090)

For more information on mineral ownership in the UK see: [Legislation & policy: mineral ownership](http://www.bgs.ac.uk/mineralsuk/planning/legislation/mineralOwnership.html)

Comment: So where can i go do fieldwork, study the minerals and make geological maps ?

Comment: Do i need to be geologist to get permission to mine and study minerals ?

Comment: You should ask these follow up questions as individual questions. Same too for the question about mineral locations in the Midlands